# wp_set_object_terms timing out?

Tags: bulk, terms

I have a list of 350 or so terms that I am trying to set to a post. Here's my code:

```
add_action('init', 'add_cities_to_story');
function add_cities_to_story() { 
    $cities_list = get_term_children('115', 'location'); // MA
    wp_set_object_terms('632', $cities_list, 'location'); 
}
```

The trouble is that it appears to timeout about 3/4 of the way through the list.

Also, any ideas how to bulk *remove* the tags from a post? :)

Comment: You should be careful with wp_set_object_terms() because by default it will remove any existing terms on the object that aren't duplicated in the $terms argument. In this case you'd lose all locations not in $cities_list.

Comment: FWIW I'd also propose that you revisit the decisions that lead you to want to add hundreds of terms to a single post. That is probably not the right way to go in terms of taxonomy design and if used regularly will give you a lot of headaches as your database grows over time.

Comment: @Jeremy, thanks for the comment! My original goal was to get the "empty" terms to display on the front end by having a post associated with each term. It turns out I didn't need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with terms is known to be very heavy operation.

The common tweak recommended is to use [`wp_defer_term_counting()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_defer_term_counting) to temporarily disable updating of terms count (which is stored persistently in database and so must be updated when you change terms).

Comment: Would I just include that to run in my function _before_ I use wp_set_object_terms?

Comment: @Jonathan turn off before, turn back on after